# JWT token not being validated

Tags: asp.net, jwt

My JWT token validation is not working.

In the following first 3 code blocks are JWT generation server. and last is my resource server.  Both are ASP.NET Server applications.   JWT generator is generating the code and when i used Postman to send that code in Header Authentication to access secured ([Authorized]) WebAPI  I get unauthorized message  back.   I guess I am making some mistakes configuring both application

**The start up class is:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }


    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat()
        };

        // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

    }
}
```

**CustomOAuthProvider**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace AuthorizationServer.Api.Providers
{
    public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {

        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });


            if (context.UserName != context.Password)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect");
                //return;
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Manager"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Supervisor"));

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {
                         "audience", "099153c2625149bc8ecb3e85e03f0022"
                    }
                });

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomJWTFormat**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace AuthorizationServer.Api.Formats
{
    public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
    {
        private readonly string _issuer = "http://jwtauthzsrv.azurewebsites.net";

        public CustomJwtFormat()
        {
        }

        public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
        {
            if (data == null)   {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            }

            string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = "IxrAjDoa2FqElO7IhrSrUJELhUckePEPVpaePlS_Xaw";
            var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
            var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);
            var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
            var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, "099153c2625149bc8ecb3e85e03f0022", data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);
            return jwt;
        }

        public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**And now here is my Resource start up code**

```
namespace ResourceServer.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }


        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var issuer = "http://jwtauthzsrv.azurewebsites.net";
            var audience = "099153c2625149bc8ecb3e85e03f0022";
            var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("IxrAjDoa2FqElO7IhrSrUJELhUckePEPVpaePlS_Xaw");


            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                    },
                    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnValidateIdentity = context =>
                        {
                            context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("newCustomClaim", "newValue"));
                            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the request you make with Postman?

Comment: I selected Post with URL   http://localhost:18303/api/protected
Then in header  i put this Key Value  The token generated from earlier request             **Authorization   Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImEiLCJzdWIiOiJhIiwicm9sZSI6WyJNYW5hZ2VyIiwiU3VwZXJ2aXNvciJdLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vand0YXV0aHpzcnYuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQiLCJhdWQiOiIwOTkxNTNjMjYyNTE0OWJjOGVjYjNlODVlMDNmMDAyMiIsImV4cCI6MTQ5MDQ0MDc2MCwibmJmIjoxNDkwNDM4OTYwfQ.DnC4Pn0vf1D3mlMlbskM8MXd_8_4JepX0La4GSeJMu0**

Comment: If you go to https://jwt.io, to the debugger section and try the token, you will see that it marks it invalid. So, it seems that the problem is when generating the token.

Comment: I went to jwt.io and entered  "IxrAjDoa2FqElO7IhrSrUJELhUckePEPVpaePlS_Xaw" in VERIFY SIGNATURE text box at bottom and click the checkbox "secret base64 encoded"   The message turn to Verified

Comment: Somehow previous token on jwt.io is not extracting "PAYLOAD:DATA" but then i generated another token and then the Payload starting show data that was send in the code the token is **eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImEiLCJzdWIiOiJhIiwicm9sZSI6WyJNYW5hZ2VyIiwiU3VwZXJ2aXNvciJdLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3Lm15d2Vic2l0ZS5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE0OTA0NDU4ODIsIm5iZiI6MTQ5MDQ0NDA4Mn0.WIv_B30y9o8bfLFnqotrGupoqHAGRNjnQzS47ZoBZxo**

Comment: I still can't manage it to appear as verified. But, in any case, it is a bad idea to share your secret key. So consider deleting the question and post it again if you like without the secret. So far, the only think I found to be odd, is to change the `var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);` to `var key = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);
            var signingKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(key, "HS256");`

Comment: Thanks for the advise. This is just a test project and secret is not a real secret. So no worries

Answer (score 0):

JWT can't be validated in jwt.io as they need a public key to have they siganture decifred, and that page doesn't have that. That is the a process made through the AccessTokenValidation extension or middleware that your web api should have.
I had a similar problem, I believe it is related with the timout as, as I implemented Katana logging for seeing more detail (it is an extra middleware layer that has to be built inside the Startup.cs class) it starting working for me, without checking any logs or implement any further solution.
I followed this tutorial and deleted the examples that procude exceptions in it.

https://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/logging-in-the-owin-world-with-microsoft-owin--introduction

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).